# Extract URL value if has sku in the url

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am having a url like
http://192.168.1.5/wpp/base/product/sku/4t4tsdg

if sku word is present in the url i need need to extract the value `4t4tsdg` using regex. i am using in wordpress

i tried using `/product/sku/(.*/?)$` but unable to get it

php code i used in wordpress

```
add_rewrite_rule('/product/sku/(.*/?)$', 'index.php?product_sku=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Comment: It should have worked. Share the actual code?

Comment: How are you verifying that it is not working?

Comment: I'm suspecting of your anchor and your non escaped forward slash (you shouldn't escape them anyway)... can you try a regex like this: `.*\/sku\/(.*)`

Comment: @FedericoPiazza The slashes do not worry `add_rewrite_rule` function -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: @FedericoPiazza not working

Comment: @anubhava i am using http://www.regexr.com/ to test it

Comment: Testing a WP specific rewrite rule on regexr doesn't make much sense. Anyway Do you have a regexr demo link showing this regex is not working?

Comment: Hi, all. i have figured it out and released the plugin :) https://wordpress.org/plugins/sku-shortlink-for-woocommerce/